# Using logical operators on loops results in contradiction

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, for-loop, logical-operators

I'm dealing with a really, really weird issue in JavaScript. I'm working on a validator script that loops through a list of fields with jQuery. Each validation is tied to a regular expression on an object that goes like this:

```
var formats = {

      email: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g,

      phone: /(?!:\A|\s)(?!(\d{1,6}\s+\D)|((\d{1,2}\s+){2,2}))(((\+\d{1,3})|(\(\+\d{1,3}\)))\s*)?((\d{1,6})|(\(\d{1,6}\)))\/?(([ -.]?)\d{1,5}){1,5}((\s*(#|x|(ext))\.?\s*)\d{1,5})?(?!:(\Z|\w|\b\s))/gm,

      numeric: /(\d+)(((.|,)\d+)+)?/g,

      url: /^((http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(\/[a-zA-Z0-9%:\/-_\\?\.'~]*)?$/gi

    };
```

Then I've created a function that given two parameters, the format and the test subject, returns `true` or `false` (merely a wrapper of the `test` method for the RegExp object):

```
validy.is = function(what, str) {
    return formats[what].test(str);
};
```

On a jQuery collection, I have `INPUT` elements with classes named accordingly to each format:

```
<input type="text" class="field email" id="field-1-1" />
<input type="text" class="field phone" id="field-1-2" />
...
```

Then, my validation function goes like this:

```
    formBuilder.validate = function() {
      console.info("=== STARTING VALIDATE ===");

      var isValid = true;
      var allFields = $(".field", formBuilder.form).toArray();
      var validable = ["email","phone","numeric","url"];

      var errors = {
        "email": "Debés ingresar una dirección de e-mail válida (por ejemplo: juanperez@gmail.com).",
        "phone": "Debés ingresar un número de teléfono válido.",
        "numeric": "Debés ingresar un número.",
        "url": "Debés ingresar una dirección Web válida (por ejemplo: www.misitio.com.ar)."
      };

      for (var f = 0; f < allFields.length; f++) {

        var $field = $(allFields[f]);

        console.info($field);
        console.info("--> Field has classes: " + $field.attr("class"));

        for (var v = 0; v < validable.length; v++) {

          var validableClass = validable[v];

          if ($field.hasClass(validableClass)) {

            console.info("--> Validating against " + validableClass + " with value <<" + $field.val() + ">>");
            console.info("--> Test result: validy.is(validableClass, $field.val()) = " + vw.validy.is(validableClass, $field.val()));
            console.info("--> Last value of isValid = " + isValid);

            isValid = isValid && (validy.is(validableClass, $field.val()) ? true : false);

            console.info("--> Value of isValid is now = " + isValid);
            break;

          };

        }

        console.info("** Status of isValid: " + isValid + " **");

        if (!isValid) {

          console.info("--> Invalid field detected");
          //vw.popoverError($field, "Error", errors[validableClass]);
          break;

        };

      };

      return isValid;

    };
```

The problem with it is that even when the field value is valid and `isValid == true`, when it does the `isValid == isValid && ...` operation, `isValid` ends up being `false`.

How can it be possible for a `true && true` expression to throw `false`.

I know there must be some stupidity I can't see, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone lend a hand on this one?

Thanks!

**Update 1**

Originally, the line:

`isValid = isValid && (validy.is(validableClass, $field.val()) ? true : false);`

was

`isValid &= validy.is(validableClass, $field.val();`

**Update 2**

At some point, apparently the `test` method is returning `1` or `0` instead of `true` or `false`. But I can't pinpoint the exact moment when it happens.

**Update 3**

So it turns out that I was misusing the `&=` operator as mentioned in the comments. But...

`isValid = isValid && validy.is(validableClass, $field.val());`

...returns `false` when `isValid == true` and `validy.is` returns `true` independently.

**Update 4**

Changed the `validy.is` definition according to answer by CaffGeek:

```
    validy.is = function(what, str) {

      return !!formats[what].test(str);

    };
```

It had no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: sidenote: the tertiary `variable = condition ? true : false` is not necessary - just write `variable = condition`

Comment: I know, before that I was using `variable &= condition`.

Comment: is there a specific reason why your console.log statement logs `vw.validy.is(validableClass, $field.val())` while your actual condition is `validy.is(validableClass, $field.val())`? what is `vw`?

Comment: Step through it in Firebug to see where the variable is going false and see if something is false when you expect it to be true.

Comment: You should step through the issue using Chrome Dev Tools Debugger to make sure the values you think are being evaluated are correct. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts

Comment: @jbabey Sorry, vw is a typo. Fixing it now.

Comment: @JoelAlejandro `&=` is not what you think it is. see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators).

Comment: @jbabey That would explain it.

Comment: Are you testing every format in each field?  I'm trying to follow your code.

Comment: @CaffGeek nope, I'm testing it only if it has a 'testeable' class. As in, a class which is enumerated in the "validable" array.

Comment: Right, but it wasn't clear if you were potentially testing a 'email' field with the 'url' format.  I don't think you were though, so that's good.  I updated my answer with a streamlined, set based approach to your problem.  Not tested, but it simplifies your code, and might help you spot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
validy.is = function(what, str) {
    return formats[what].test(str);
};
```

to this to ensure it's a boolean result.

```
validy.is = function(what, str) {
    return !!formats[what].test(str);
};
```

I haven't tested this, but you don't need all the loops with jQuery.  It's set based.  You can simplify your code along this manner.

```
formBuilder.validate = function() {
    console.info("=== STARTING VALIDATE ===");

    var isValid = true;
    var allFields = $(".field", formBuilder.form).toArray();
    var validable = ["email", "phone", "numeric", "url"];

    var errors = {
        "email": "Debés ingresar una dirección de e-mail válida (por ejemplo: juanperez@gmail.com).",
        "phone": "Debés ingresar un número de teléfono válido.",
        "numeric": "Debés ingresar un número.",
        "url": "Debés ingresar una dirección Web válida (por ejemplo: www.misitio.com.ar)."
    };

    var failedFields = $('EMPTYJQUERYSET');

    $.each(validable, function(index, className) {
        failedFields.add(
            allFields.filter('.' + className).filter(function(index) {
                return ! validy.is(validableClass, $(this).val());
            });
        );
    });

    isValid = !!(failedFields.length == 0);

    console.info("** Status of isValid: " + isValid + " **");

    if (!isValid) {
        console.info("--> Invalid field detected");
        //vw.popoverError($field, "Error", errors[validableClass]);
        break;
    };

    return isValid;
};
```

Comment: I'm testing your solution at the moment, will let you know!

Answer (score 3):

I use !!variable a lot to make sure that the variable exists and that it has a positive value.

if it is undefined or false, !!variable will return false, if it is defined and true or has a value (not 0) it will return true